# Self-hosted blog Admin Panel Forwarding to WP.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I was goofing with the settings (first problem) in the "General" tab of my wp-admin panel on my self-hosted blog.

There are two settings: Wordpress.com URL and Blog URL (or something). They were both originally set to my self-hosted `www.domain.com/blog`. I thought if I changed the Wordpress.com URL to an empty blog that I set up on Wordpress `www.myblog.wordpress.com` that it would simply connect the two blogs so that my site went into the Wordpress.com directory.

**This did not happen.**

Now, if I visit MY self-hosted URL, I see my blog, but it's clearly missing a stylesheet. And now I can't access the admin panel of my own blog. I don't know what happened.

Can I remedy this? Is there a file on my server where I can just edit the line that I changed and switch it back to what it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of two questions in one, but to solve your first problem and get your blog working again you need to edit your MySQL database. If you have access to PhpMyAdmin open that up and find the `wp_options` table. Inside the table there are two values to change `siteurl` and `home` are the names I believe. Change these both to `http://example.com/blog` or whatever the appropriate link is and this hould get things working again.

The second question, if I am understanding correctly, is how do you cross post from a self-hosted WP install to a WP.com install simultaneously?

Comment: I'll try phpMyAdmin route. I do have access to that. And yes, your understanding is correct with regards to cross-posting.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, Josh. Any ideas for the second or should I post another question? I'll search the stack to see if it's been asked before.

Comment: @jon Two questions: 1. Why do you want to cross post in two locations? This will be seen as duplicate content in search engines and 2. Will this be a one time 'move all old posts over' kind of deal or an ongoing every time you post the new posts is put in both locations thing?

Comment: It seems that Wordpress.com blogs get added to a Wordpress directory that can be searched by other bloggers. This gives dot-com bloggers a traffic advantage over those who self-host.